# Adding shortcode closing tag after a loop

Tags: loop, shortcode

I'm using a shortcode for accordion. I would like to put a loop inside this shortcode. However the closing tag seems to be unparsed.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[su_accordion]');?>

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
        echo do_shortcode('[su_spoiler title="'.get_the_title().'" open="no" style="default" icon="plus" anchor="" class=""]'.get_the_content().'[/su_spoiler]');
        echo '</div>';

    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[/su_accordion]');?>
```

The last part of the shortcode is displayed as simple text.

Any solution?

Comment: collect all of the loop's output in a variable, wrap it in the accordion shortcode, then pass that through do_shortcode.

Comment: Hi Milo, 
I tried but how can I use loop inside a variable? 
I'll update the question with other code.

Comment: Hi Milo, I tried to put the loop inside a variable but it prints the loop like a string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect all of the loop's output in a variable, wrap it in the accordion shortcode, then pass that through do_shortcode:

```
$output = '';   

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $output .= '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
        $output .= do_shortcode('[su_spoiler title="'.get_the_title().'" open="no" style="default" icon="plus" anchor="" class=""]'.get_the_content().'[/su_spoiler]');
        $output .= '</div>';

    endwhile;
else :
    $output = wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;

echo do_shortcode( '[su_accordion]' . $output . '[/su_accordion]' );
```

I've tested this with a couple of enclosing Shortcodes and got the expected output.